# Date and time keyboard shortcut for Google Docs document (not sheets)

Tags: google-docs, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to find out if I can set up a keyboard shortcut to print/type in the current date and time in a Google Docs document (not sheets). Anyone?

The best I could find is an Add-on Text Factory menu, not shortcut, but since the last few weeks is one-hour off (presumably the code does not update to day savings changes).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't such shortcut for a date and time in Google Docs.

(avail shortcuts here: **[https://support.google.com/docs/...](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/179738?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)**)

You could accomplish this task with the 3rd-party script tool like **[AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)** and set up date and time insertion upon custom defined keyboard shortcut.